# duplicate key entry when copying entry from poll to poll_logs

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot project that transfers the poll entries to poll_logs when the entries are processed through a batch process. This works fine but when the batch job restarts, this occurs:

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'

I just want to know the reason why this happens. Is it because of a mysterious occurrence between Spring and MySQL or an error on our part?

The id of the poll table has an auto_increment attribute while the id of the poll_logs doesn't.
Also, here are the queries for transferring entries to poll_logs

CopyPollItems

```
INSERT INTO poll_log SELECT * FROM poll WHERE id = <id>
```

RemovePollItems

```
DELETE FROM poll WHERE id = <id>
```

Comment: Nothing mysterious here. When your batch job restarts its copying data from `poll` that already exists in `poll_logs`. You need either to ensure that that can't happen, or use a variant of `INSERT` than handles it. See `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY...` as a starting point

Comment: I see, I'll check on it and apply the necessary measures to prevent it from happening. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a poll already present in poll_log.

Add a clause to ignore poll already present.

```
INSERT INTO poll_log SELECT * FROM poll WHERE id = <id> AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM poll_log pl WHERE pl.id = poll.id)
```